# How to clear http cache for a url in Android Webview

Tags: android, android-webview, browser-cache

I have multiple webviews in my app. I want to programatically clear cache for a particular url  in webview. How to do it? There is a clearCache() method available in Webview but it clears the cache for all webviews. I want to clear the cache for a particular webview.

Comment: the cache is per-application, so you cannot do it